# Synonym for "in terms of" (of Latin origin)

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, latin

I am trying to remember a synonym for "being" or "in terms of" ... It is a Latin word that has entered the English language.

Comment: I'm not sure that's enough context. Are you perhaps thinking of [qua](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qua) *- in the capacity or character of*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[Qua](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qua)** : in the capacity or character of : as

Comment: Nah, FumbleFingers is the best, he beat me by about 15 seconds :).